# Microsoft Cognitive API Image Search

Tags: c#, android, image, azure-cognitive-services

Im trying to use the Microsoft API of Bing image described [here](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/56b43f0ccf5ff8098cef3808/operations/571fab09dbe2d933e891028f)

I only want to use the image insights to find similar images by sending a image at the body of the post request, as the doc says i can provide a url or the image.

The image is being captured by a phone camera and sent to the api, the idea is to end up getting similar image results.

At first i was getting a error saying the 'q' parameter was required, but i do not want to use a search query just the image.

So i changed the ContentType to "multipart/form-data" and used "/search?modulesRequested=similarimages"

This seems to do something as now i dont get any error, the api response is just a empty string so im really lost here...

Heres my code to send the request.

```
        public async Task<string> GetImageInsights(byte[] image)
    {
        var uri = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?modulesRequested=similarimages";

        var response = await RequestHelper.MakePostRequest(uri, new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(image)), key, "multipart/form-data");

        var respString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return respString;
    }
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakePostRequest(string uri, string body, string key, string contentType)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        // Request headers
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);

        // Request body
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);

        using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
        {
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);
            return await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        }
    }
```

Im using C# with Xamarin on Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the service to work correctly, both a name and filename are required for the form part:

```
public async Task<string> GetImageInsights(byte[] image)
{
    var uri = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?modulesRequested=similarimages";

    var response = await RequestHelper.MakePostRequest(uri, image, key);

    var respString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return respString;
}

class RequestHelper
{ 
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> MakePostRequest(String uri, byte[] imageData, string key)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);

            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(imageData), "image", "image.png");

            return await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is still not working, it just returns an empty string, what that means? shouldnt it return some kind of error?

Comment: I'm assuming that an empty result means similar images were not found.  What happens if you try a common image from the internet?

Comment: It turned out the empty result was the server returning 404 and was caused by my image being larger than 1MB, once fixed that im getting a error for missing the 'q' parameter, if i use imgurl it does not ask for the query why using the post body does?

Comment: Are you using the code I posted?  Per [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn760791.aspx), > > If you set the modulesRequested query parameter to RecognizedEntities, you may specify the image by setting the imgUrl query parameter to the URL of the image or you may specify the binary of the image in the body of a POST request. If you specify the image in the body of a POST request, you must specify this header and set its value to multipart/form-data.